# str response to csv format

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas

I am working with some device that returns values as `<class 'str'>` my code generates response in one csv row.
I want this response as one column of csv file

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([])
i = 2
while i< 4:

    df = my_instrument.query('READ?')
    # df return type <class 'str'>
    df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df))
    df2 = (pd.concat([df2, df1], ignore_index=True))
    i += 1
df2.to_csv('Response.csv')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create list of `DataFrame`s by append in loop and only once call `pd.concat`:

```
dfs = []
i = 2
while i < 4:

    df = my_instrument.query('READ?')
    # df return type <class 'str'>
    df1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(df))
    dfs.append(df1)
    i += 1

df2 = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
df2.to_csv('Response.csv')
```